# macos: change default "zoom in" for any application?

Tags: macos, zoom

Many applications I use, like Vim, Safari, and Chrome, support "Zoom In" and "Zoom Out" to magnify the size of the screen, or return it to standard size.

Every time I start some applications, I zoom them "in" a bunch of times, and would like to set a default zoom level for them, so I don't have to do this all the time.

Is there a way to do this? I'm ok with using 3rd party tools!

Comment: Probably not as each app does this its own way. There are ways to mac the mac screen zoom e.g. in accesibility but these chnage the window soze and not just the contents of the window

Comment: I meant that each app does have a way for saving its own defaults. e.g. the answer on Safari, Firefox can set its zoom level as can Emacs and Terminal/iTerm

Answer (score 2):

I don't know about the others, but Safari has a prefs page dedicated to Zoom levels, per site, with a global default…

[image]

Comment: Would the downvoter care to comment on this?

Comment: yeah I'm not sure why it would be downvoted? I am looking for a general solution for all apps, but this is helpful for the Safari case! Thanks!

Comment: There is no 'general solution' as each app is going to handle this differently - already pointed out in comments above.